# Getting com.aspose.cells.CellsException: Invalid Excel2007Xlsx file format

Tags: aspose-cells

I use **aspose/cells/aspose-cells-8.4.0.jar** version of **ASPOSE CELLS** library for processing files.
When I try to open file with extension xlsb, I get **com.aspose.cells.CellsException: Invalid Excel2007Xlsx file format** error. Interestingly, I have given file as **xlsb** but Aspose library is treating itas **Xlsx** file.

I have found that aspose-cells-8.4.0 version is capable of processing xlsb file format.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using older version (aspose-cells-8.4.0.jar), so this might be a bug in the older version  that you are using or some other limitation. We recommend you to kindly upgrade to newer versions of [Aspose.Cells for Java](https://downloads.aspose.com/cells/java) which are more stable/robust and support to process (read, write and manipulate) all the older and newer/advanced file formats (including XLSB) of MS Excel (97-2003, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, etc.).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.